# VimEnter autocmd to change cursor shape sometimes outputs escape sequences

Tags: terminal, autocmd, cursor

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118416), I have the following in my `vimrc`:

```
augroup cursor
    au!
    autocmd VimEnter * silent !echo -ne "\e[1 q"
augroup end
```

However, this sometimes prints the following on startup:

```
^[[2;2R^[[>65;5402;1c^[]10;rgb:b2b2/b2b2/b2b2^[\^[]11;rgb:0000/0000/0000^[\
```

What is causing this? The work around I came up with was to add `autocmd VimEnter * redraw!`, but I would like to know the root cause and if there is a better way to fix this.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: Are you using tmux as well? If so, does this happen outside of tmux as well, or *only* in tmux?

Comment: Studying those sequences, the first two are CSI sequences. `^[[2;2R` is the terminal informing the application the cursor position (2, 2), `^[[>65;5402;1c` I can't find anything on without knowing your terminal (possibly "Send Device Attributes"?), and the last two are OSC sequences: `^[]10;rgb...^[\ ` and `^[]11;rgb:...^[\ `. Again, I'll need to know the terminal to begin finding out what those mean specifically, but they're setting the color of some two things. `#b2b2b2` gives a [light gray](https://www.webfx.com/web-design/color-picker/B2B2B2/). *Why* these are showing up eludes me...

Comment: @ZeroKnight This is using termite. Not using tmux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that it answers the question about the root cause but I found a better way (IMO) to reset the cursor on startup. The main problem is that vim only sends the "t_EI" escape sequence when is exiting either Insert mode or Replace mode (see :help termcap-cursor-shape) and since vim starts on Normal mode "t_EI" is not sent. An obvious solution to this is to enter and exit Insert mode on startup. This is one way to do it:

```
" Reset cursor on startup
augroup ResetCursorShape
au!
autocmd VimEnter * :normal :startinsert :stopinsert 
augroup END
```

I prefer this way over the code you referenced because even when I add the `autocmd VimEnter * redraw!` autocommand I still see the string in the command line for a split second and it is very annoying.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You ought to be able to just do `startinsert | stopinsert` (no colons, no `normal[!]`), since you need an Ex command.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thank you for your warm welcome! Do you mean changing it to `autocmd VimEnter * startinsert | stopinsert`? For some reason it doesn't work for me. It seems to run but the cursor doesn't change to the one defined in t_EI. Any ideas why that may be?

Comment: Odd, yes. Then maybe just `normal! :startinsert` etc.